# Retrieve Identity Claims in a Single Sign On project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

We have three ASP.NET MVC 5 projects working alongside. For authentication, we came up using Single Sign On, following the very simple tutorial:

[Implementation of Single Sign On (SSO) in ASP.NET MVC](http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc)

The main idea is to create a `MachineKey` shared between 3, and add the same authentication settings in 3 `web.config` files.

So now we have 3 sites called:

- SSO
- WebApp1
- WebApp2

One of our projects (`SSO`) does the job and two other depend on it. It works and we were happy but...

We are using Identity 2 claims-based authentication in the `SSO` project and when a user logs in, we add some custom claims to his "identity". This way, we have 2 separate cookies: one for Single Sign On process, and a second one for saving claims.

Here is the C# code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string fromSite, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                // here the cookie which contains claims *is created* by Identity 2

                // here we create the cookie used for Single Sing On
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);

                // redirecting
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fromSite))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl)) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }

                return Redirect(string.Format("{0}{1}", fromSite, returnUrl));

                // other cases inside switch
                .
                .
                .
        }
    }
```

When a user goes from `SSO` site to another, say `WebApp1`, he remains logged in but we lost claims.

Is there any way to "merge" these 2 cookies and retrieve the claims in another site?

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed this! Here is the sulotion:

Create 3 new MVC 5 projects with Individual Authentication. Add a same `MachineKey` in their `web.config` files inside `system.web` tag. Now you are done and every thing works like a charm! Easy peasy :) The OWIN takes care of every thing.

For better clarity, delete anything related to authentication and authorization from 2 of 3 projects. This way one of them will be the core and two others depend on it. My projects are:

- SSO
- WebApp1
- WebApp2

For example delete `AccountController.cs` and `ManageController.cs` from `Controllers` folder and remove `Account` and `Manage` folders under `Views` with their related ViewModels. You can also delete the `Startup.Auth.cs` file under `App_Start` folder in both projects, say `WebApp1` and `WebApp2`.

After all of deleting, replace the content of `Startup.cs` in that 2 projects root directory with this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(WebApp1.Startup))]
// for the other one, rename the WebApp1 to WebApp2
namespace WebApp1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The above code was originally part of `Startup.Auth.cs` file which you have deleted! Now OWIN knows the type of cookie and can read it.

There is one thing left: when an unauthorized user, who has not logged in yet, goes to `WebApp1`, he will see the `HTTP 401` error page and will not redirect to `SSO`'s login page. You should handle this case in any manner you want. I think a `Filter` would do the job.

Hope i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider we have 4 projects.

- WebAppMain(This project contains the login page)
- App2
- App3
- App4

If you are using ASP.Net Identity you need to add code for that in Startup class(Not in main project, this for App2, 3 and 4).

> One important thing is, keep all Owin related dlls in same version.
>   Otherwise SSO won't work.

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(ABC.Startup))]
namespace ABC
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

                app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
                app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
                app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
                app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    CookieDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainNameForSSO"],
                    CookieName = "SSOCookie",

                });

        }
    }
}
```

Use a appsettings variable to store domain

```
<add key="DomainNameForSSO" value=".test.com"/>
```

Use the same CookieName and CookieDomain in main project Startup.Auth.cs file.

Add a common machine key to all project's web.config file.

```
<machineKey
       validationKey="{Update this value}"
       decryptionKey="{Update this value}"
       validation="SHA1"
       decryption="AES"
    />
```

you can generate machine using online tools or custom code is available on internet.

Once it is done, create a Custom Authorize attribute like below.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CustomAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) ||
                                     filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);
            if (skipAuthorization) return;

            var authManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            if (authManager == null || authManager.User == null || authManager.User.Identity == null || !authManager.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                UnAuthorizedProcess(filterContext);// handle unathorized request here, we can redirect the request to main project from here
            }
            else
            {
                AuthorizedProcess(filterContext);// Do the default action or if we have any custom validation, write here.
            }
        }
}
```

Add attribute in all actions/controllers need to authorized.

```
 [CustomAuthorize]
 public ActionResult Dashboard()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

you have to give full URL as returnURL parameter to the main website.